# how to remove subquery from sql involving max()

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query like this

```html
select * from tablename where ID in(select max(ID) from tablename )
```

I want to remove subquery to improve performace. Please suggest me,How to do it
   Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention your RDBMS, but in MS-SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

Comment: Doesn't work in MySQL. I'm not saying that it's wrong, just for the information, due to the ambiguous question of the OP.

Comment: I know. That's why I said this answer applies to MS SQL.

Comment: @volerag: It is mentioned in the answer that this is for MS-SQL

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MS SQL Server; you can achieve it like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM tablename
ORDER BY ID DESC
```

In MYSQL You can use :

```
SELECT * from tablename 
ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

for  Oracle :

```
  SELECT  *FROM 
(
   SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY ID desc
)
  WHERE rownum <= 1  ORDER BY ID ;
```

For  MS-SQL :

```
  SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tablename ORDER BY ID DESC
```

For MY SQL :

```
  select * from tablename order by ID  desc limit 1
```